# Почему crontab выполняет скрипт python дважды? Ubuntu 18.04

Tags: python, linux, ubuntu, crontab

В crontab -e такой текст (предполагалось что скрипт будет выполняться 1 раз каждые 2 часа):

```
0 */2 * * * /usr/bin/python3 /home/Myscript/script.py
```

В итоге crontab почему-то выполняет его дважды (подряд) каждые 2 часа, вместо 1 раза.

Сам скрипт:

```
from functions import *
def payday_notifications():
    dbconnector = mysql.connector.connect(host="localhost", user=db_name",
                                          passwd="db_pass",
                                          database="db_name")

    def func(i):
        it =[item for item in user_ids[i:i+100]]
        return it

    mycursor = dbconnector.cursor()
    mycursor.execute("SELECT `user_id` FROM `users` WHERE (`food` <= 0)")
    ids = mycursor.fetchall()
    mycursor.close()

    if (ids):
        user_ids = []
        for i in ids:
            user_ids.append(i[0])

        list = user_ids
        for j in range(len(user_ids)//100 + (0 if len(user_ids)%100==0 else 1)):
            i = j*100
            user_ids_str = ', '.join(str(x) for x in func(i))
            message = "У вас кончились еда в кафе!"
            send_notifications_keyboard(user_ids_str, message)
            time.sleep(0.05)
   if __name__ == '__main__':
       payday_notifications()
```

Скрипт просто делает рассылку в боте.

Comment: Хм, что значит `*2`?

Comment: Случайно пропустил символ, исправил

Comment: возможно cron запущен дважды? или команда внесена в несколько файлов (для пользователя и для root'а)...

Comment: как это можно проверить? команду вносил один раз, через root'a

Comment: первое — `ps aux |grep cron`; второе — `grep -rv . /var/spool/cron/ /etc/crontab`...

Comment: да, само собой, подразумевалось `grep -r`, без `-v`...

Comment: к счастью или к несчастью, проблема решилась сама.